# How do I get my custom logger's logging level from configuration?

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-logging

In .NET Core, the logging level may be configured based on an hierarchical configuration model:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/#configure-logging

Now, when I write a custom logger, derived from [`ILogger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger), how do I determine my logger's logging level at runtime, so I can return a proper result in [`ILogger::IsEnabled()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger.isenabled)?